# Выравнивание значения в ESP на 16 байт

Tags: c, ассемблер

Дизассемблировал такую простую программу:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub esp, 10h
mov eax, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello, world\n"
```

Строка `and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h` мне всегда мозолила глаза, а ее смысл в книгах по реверсу не объясняется. Пишут, что это выравнивание значения в `ESP` по 16-байтной границе, но "выравнивание", "обнуление первых четырех бит" и "16 байт" у меня никак не складываются в завершенную идею. Что здесь происходит? Для чего это? Почему для выравнивания на 16 байт надо обнулить 4 бита?

Выравнивание я понимаю как заполнение кусков памяти до кратности какому-то числу. Так, например, выровненные секции в PEшнике заполняются в конце нулями, как показывает hiew.

Обнуление первых четырех бит `ESP` - это как умножение на `2^4`. Но почему компилятору не жалко разбазаривать столько адресов?

Comment: "Обнуление первых четырех бит ESP - это как умножение на 2^4" - нет, это как обнуление 4 бит. Т.е., например если было 0xFF (255), от после обнуления 4 бит это будет 0xF0 (240).

Comment: Имел в виду, что после этого обнуления значение ESP будет делиться на 16, но не так сказал.

Comment: Предположим, у нас есть число 521 в десятичной системе счисления, что надо сделать что бы привести его вниз к числу, делящемуся на 100, правильно, превратить 21 в 00 что бы получилось 500. Чему в двоичной системе счисления равно 10000 ? оно равно 16 десятичному. таким образом по аналогии с тем что мы только что делали в десятичной системе, что бы сделать двоичное число делящимся на 16 надо сбросить младшие 4 бита. Собственно младшие 4 бита двоичного числа - это остаток от деления на 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выравнивание на `n` - это изменение значения так, чтобы оно было кратно `n`.
Соответственно есть выравнивание "вниз" и "вверх". Для `n` равного степени двойки (`n = 2^k`) выравнивания числа `x` рассчитываются следующим образом:

```
x & ~(n - 1) // вниз, до ближайшего меньшего числа кратного n
(x + n - 1) & ~(n - 1) // вверх, до ближайшего большего числа кратного n
```

Неиспользуемые куски памяти называются *padding* и строго говоря к выравниванию отношения не имеет. При этом они могут быть ничем не заполнены (`dup alignment (?)`).

Поскольку стек растет вниз, то его выравниваниют снизу, т.е. при помощи

```
and esp, ~0xf
```

Answer (score 1):

Стек "растет" в сторону уменьшения адресов:

[image: Изображение стека]

То есть получив `ESP` и желая его выровнять, отсекаются младшие 4 бита (при этом `ESP` станет указывать на участок памяти, находящийся через некоторое количество байт от "прошлого" `ESP`). Тогда да, в стеке могут образовываться "дырки". Так сказано в документации, что `ESP` выравнен по границе 16 бит. Насчёт целесообразности - вопрос к разработчикам, но они утверждают, что это увеличивает производительность.

Comment: Не думаю, что `sub esp, 10h` относится в этом фрагменте кода к выравниванию стека при входе. Скорее всего в стеке резервируется 16 байт для последующего заполнения аргументами вызова какой-то функции.

Comment: Да, согласен, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Собственно, комментарий как раз касался утверждения (неверного) `(при этом ESP будет указывать, скорее всего, на уже занятое место), а потом вычитается 16 бит (чтобы попасть в еще не занятую область памяти)`